# iOS Progress View with background image and highlighting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider, uiprogressview

I've been searching around cocoa controls and haven't been able to find a progress view that can give me a background image and it puts highlights the image with a color as the progress continues.

For reference I am talking about something as such:

[image]

I've only found things that highlight the image but you control the placement with a `UISlider` below it. Does anything like this exist somewhere? Or is there a simple solution for assigning properties to the `UIProgressView` to do this?

UPDATE:

So I am using a `UIImageView` behind a `UISlider`, that currently looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code for adding the `UISlider`:

```
-(void)addBottomMostHiddenView{
    _myToolbarHiddenView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:
                            CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 40, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
    [_myToolbarHiddenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2 alpha:0.8]];

    [_slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [_slider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    _slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    _slider.maximumValue = 320.0;
    _slider.continuous = YES;
    _slider.value = 25.0;
    _slider.thumbTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [_myToolbarHiddenView addSubview:_slider];

    [self.view addSubview:_myToolbarHiddenView];
}
```

The waveform Image is added elsewhere with:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:responseObject];
            image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40);
            [_myToolbarHiddenView addSubview:image];
```

Now I just need to get rid of the "thumbImage" ("read only" property it seems) and the bar, and add highlighting over everything. Any thoughts? It doesn't seem that I can get rid of the bar. Also I can adjust the height of the bar to overlay the whole image either it seems.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're looking for.  Are you looking for a progress bar that uses separate images on the left and right portions?

Comment: If that's what you're looking for, the default `UIProgressBar` does that.  `progressImage` is used for the portion on the left (the red part in your image)  while `trackImage` is used for the portion on the right (the dark portion in your image)

Comment: I am looking for a progress bar that has a background image, and then as time progresses that image is highlighted by a another color. 

In the image shown, theres a waveform as the background image, and the orange overlay progresses as the song continues.

Comment: That's more or less how `UIProgressBar` works if you use `progressImage` and `trackImage` unless you need them to be dynamic images (e.g. showing average amplitude of some wave form) then you'll need to roll your own.

Comment: And when I would click, let say in the middle of the image, everything to the left would be highlighted?

Comment: UIProgressView is an output only view.  If you're looking for a Control (providing input) the analog would be `UISlider`  It also allows you to specify images to be used on the left and right halves of the control (and the thumb, which looks to be empty in your pic)

Comment: All things considered, for the look and functionality you're trying to get, I think you'll be best off just creating a custom control.  It'll probably be quicker than you think :)

Comment: I guess it'll be fun learning how to make a modular control